# C# Entity Framework using PostgreSQL, NPGSQL and stored procedures returning a table result parameter errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, stored-procedures

Using .Net Framework 4.5, Entity Framework 6.0.0.0, and NPGSQL, I am trying to update the model from the database and use a stored procedure that returns a table result from a PostgeSQL stored procedure (function).

I am getting an error for each column that comes from the stored procedure that states the column

> ... has a parameter direction value 'null', which is not valid. Please use 'IN', 'OUT', or 'INOUT'

From my understanding of PostgreSQL, when returning a table, you don't specify `IN` or `OUT`.

Is there a workaround for this or am I missing a setting, etc for .Net or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

=> Your definition:

```
Create function xpto (p1 integer, p2 varchar)
RETURNS TABLE (a int, b int) ...
```

=> Change the definition

```
Create function xpto (IN p1 integer, IN p2 varchar, OUT a int, OUT b int)
RETURNS SETOF record
```